# Xcode code linking error always displays "Object: Exit" and can't change connection type

Tags: ios, xcode

I have encountered a problem with Xcode. Every time I connect any UI Element, I always see `Object: Exit` when the object is clearly a UIButton or UITextField and also I can't seem to be able to change the connection type.

[[image: An image of the prompt when I am connecting any element]]

When I click connect, Xcode sets the @IBoutlet or @IBAction but is not connected to the storyboard:

```
@IBAction func mainframe(_
    sender: Any) {

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have create the code as text rather then as a screenshot, as it is more readable. Also try and prevent saying "Thanks" etc as it takes focus away from the actual question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I took a screenshot of @IBAction because I wanted to show the circle next to it, to show people that it is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

The is happening due to the likelihood that you're not correctly selecting the right viewController in the assistant editor...

On the right panel, check if you have automatically selected and not manual mode.

Also check the custom class is set correctly in the inspector.

Comment: I have checked that it is the right viewController but idk how to check the custom class in the inspector. Thanks for helping me anyways!